Xubuntu 22.04 freezes randomly during use
I have an Asus X540S with 4GB RAM which worked fine under Windows XP. To update it I formatted the hard drive and installed Xubuntu 22.04. Most of the time it seems to work fine, then suddenly everything stops and the keyboard and mouse cease to work, the screen displaying the same unresponsive image. The only way to turn it off is by holding down the power button. I have noticed that the power and the hard disk lights are on when this occurs.
I did have some other issues (particularly with Firefox snap), but most of them seem to be resolved now. I have tried several suggestions from forums, but have failed to solve this problem. I have since upgraded to 24.04 where the problem persists.

The swap space has been increased to 4GB (on a 1TB hard drive).
I have found the /var/crash folder to be empty after the crash.
I have disabled hardware acceleration in Firefox (usually it is running when a crash occurs).
I have made some changes in the grub configuration file as suggested in a forum.
I have disabled the screensavers from autostart.

Does anyone here have any other suggestions, like how can I troubleshoot this problem?

Could it be a graphic card issue? I know it is Intel but no proprietary drivers turn up when I search for them

Update: have now installed Linux Mint and still have the random freeze issue. I suspect it's triggered by watching a video (online or offline), latest crash was watching a video in vlc player with the internet turned off and no other program running. Yet it can stay on for many hours at a time performing system updates for example.

So it's most likely a hardware issue. I have tested the Ram and it's ok. I have tested the harddrive and it's ok. I have flashed Bios to latest version. I have tried disabling power management. I have applied thermal paste to the CPU. I have changed the battery for a new compatible one. Laptop shows no signs of failure or overheating before the freeze. There is one bug that may give a clue - if I select UEFI Firmware settings in the grub menu, computer crashes immediately to Bios settings after cutting the power

I uploaded a probe on https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2d7db2ffb3 The only thing that is odd is the battery, which I replaced recently...can this cause a random freeze?

I notice there are a lot of people here NOT answering my question...just wondering if I'm in the right place or should I place my question somewhere else...?

This problem appears to be solved in this particular situation now by altering the boot menu in terminal

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Alter line with default to this by adding
intel_idle.max_cstate=1 to parameters (inside the quote marks)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
Press Ctrl+O to save changes. Enter. Ctrl+X to exit

sudo update-grub
restart computer

I also increased the swap to 8Gb, double the RAM
